# Replace a divs content for mobile devices

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, video, background, swap

Im using a jquery script (tubular) which lets you add a youtube video in the background of a page by attaching the the main wrapper in a div.

A video in the background does not play on a mobile device as you know so the page does not render right, Im looking for a way to swap or substitute the wrapper for another wrapper for the video will not play when mobile is detected. I guess I can use a media query for size (min-width:765, lets say).

The jquery attaches to the wrapper below:

```
 <body>
 <div id="wrapper"> //<- video starts here 100% width and height //
```

(content continues here)..

So, ideally when mobile (or screen size <765) is detected a swap occors to:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper-mobile">
```

(same content continues here as above without video in the background.
So basically the div is swapped out for mobile. Hope Im being clear.. when the jquery sees the id:wrapper it begins to play so I need to swap it.
thanks in advance.. this maybe simple but Im having a time of it.

Answer (score 0):

I placed the fallback image in the body of the site, defined the video id as a data attribute in an existing div on the page, and I decided to not define a div in my tubular call so it would create its own div, but you would replace `#tubular-container` with whatever your div is that holds the video. Then I decided to just use the media query method you mentioned.

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width:765px){
    #tubular-container {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

JS

```
var videourl = $('#video-div').data('videoid');
$('#video-div').tubular({videoId: videourl});
```

Though I prefer to hide mine using CSS, you could probably also use a mobile detection script and hide the div using javascript, for example:

```
if(isMobile()){ 
    $('#tubular-container').hide(); 
}
```

I would prefer for there to be a background image fallback built into the plugin, something that detects if autoplay is disabled and uses the fallback image instead, but this is my workaround.